# TextView setText AlertDialog delayed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am working on an activity that contains a TextView in the layout that is clickable. The onClick method activates the opening of an alert dialog that contains the possible values of the TextView (3 different possible values (0),(1),(2)). (An AlertDialog must be used to get the values, a Spinner would not work). int BUSselection is declared to be -1 at the start of the program.

```
public void showStartingDialog(){
        DialogFragment dialog = new StartingDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "StartingDialogFragment");
    }
    public void onBUSDialogSelect(DialogFragment dialog, int which)
    {BUSselection = which;}

public void changeStarting(View v) //OnClick method
{
     showStartingDialog();
     TextView basic = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.startingBox);
     if(BUSselection==0)
     {
         basic.setText("0");
     }
     else if (BUSselection ==1)
     {
         basic.setText("1");
     }
     else if (BUSselection ==2)
     {
         basic.setText("2");
     }
     else
     {

     }
}
```

Basically this program is supposed to take the selected options of the List in the AlertDialog ("0" at position 0, "1" at position 1, "2" at position 2) and put those values into the TextView. However, my problem is that when I select position 1, the 1 does not appear in the TextView until I click a second time (upon which the alert dialog shows up again). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, my best guess would be that you could try and force the TextView to update by calling invalidate().

For example:

```
TextView basic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.startingBox);
.
.
basic.setText("1");
.
.
v.invalidate();  // forces view to refresh its components
```

Note, that v must refer to the view that contains your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `showStartingDialog()` returns before the dialog finishes.
The lines after its call should be placed into the `onBUSDialogSelect()` method.

Something like this:

```
public void showStartingDialog() {
    DialogFragment dialog = new StartingDialogFragment();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "StartingDialogFragment");
}

public void onBUSDialogSelect(DialogFragment dialog, int which) {
    BUSselection = which;
    TextView basic = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.startingBox);
    if(BUSselection==0) {
         basic.setText("0");
    } else if (BUSselection ==1) {
         basic.setText("1");
    } else if (BUSselection ==2) {
         basic.setText("2");
    } else {

    }
}

// OnClick method
public void changeStarting(View v) {
     showStartingDialog();
}
```